# Acumatica field no longer truncates after update

Tags: acumatica

We have upgraded an instance from 6.1 to build 20.114.0020 and during testing of a custom data entry page the client has reported receiving the following.

> Error: Updating the 'DACName' record failed
> because data in some field is too long.

We can confirm data is properly truncated in the 6.1 production environment and a review shows uniform field declaration on the database side and DAC declaration.

```
    public abstract class platformOrdNbr : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBString(30)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Platform Order Nbr")]
    public virtual string PlatformOrdNbr { get; set; }
```

I have tried additional steps such as setting `DBCC TRACEOFF (460,-1);` on the database level as well setting the `InputMask = ""` within the DAC field declaration.

Any and all potential insight on this issue would be appreciated. I must be mindful that data exceeding the field length must be truncated, the field cannot be increased in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ran into this with our product as well.  When Acumatica re-engineered the ORM for 2020 R1, they changed the behavior of the product so that it no longer automatically truncates data to the SQL specification.  We opened a ticket about this and were told to add code to truncate at the DAC level.

set {this._ItemDescription = value.Length <= 40 ? value : value.Substring(0, 40);}`

Comment: We're creating a derived attribute to accomplish this automatically based on the length property, I'll post here for reference when complete.